# Touchpad doesn't work after suspending the computer

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, ubuntu-gnome

As the title says, I am dealing with this annoying problem in my laptop (ASUS X455L) with Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS. Since I do not know a lot about computers I would be grateful if someone could tell me in the easiest possible way how to solve this. I've read in a couple of other forums that to solve this I should create a file named 10_reset_psmouse in /etc/pm/sleep.d/ with the following code in it:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Action script ensure that psmouse works before a hibernate
# Licence GPL2

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
SELF=reset-psmouse

# On suspend|hibernate, reset psmouse

case "${1}" in
hibernate)
# nothing
;;
resume|thaw)
rmmod psmouse;
modprobe psmouse
;;
esac
```

I was not successful when I tried this, if any of you come with a new idea it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing your should do is upgrade your linux kernel to 4.4 stable.
Google the instructions.  It is easy.

The second thing you should do is take a peek at the new 16.04 and see if that fixes your problem.

The third thing you should do, which is not so fun, is upgrade your bios.
After that file a bug (quickly) typing "ubuntu-bug linux" in terminal.